# How to remove files starting with a particular letter

Tags: linux, bash

I want to rm all files in a directory not starting with the letter I or N - what is the easiest way to do it in bash?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
rm [^IN]*
```

The `[^IN]` is a pattern that matches any character except `I` or `N` - this syntax is described in the [Pattern Matching](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) section of the bash manual.

Comment: +1 also in bash: `shopt -s extglob; rm !([IN]*)` which is more useful when the list of files you want excluded is more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "[^NI]*" -delete
```

Obviously, this option is worse ;)

Comment: **1)** he asked for files *not* starting with I/N  **2)** `find` is recursive unless you add `maxdepth`  **3)** you could use the `-delete` flag instead of `-exec rm` :)

Comment: This recurses into subdirectories, the OP wanted current directory only.

Comment: @Martin Sorry, yo're right ;)